# Preserve newlines with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri in a Rails 3 app. It ignores

```
<br/>
```

tags. I'd like to replace such tags with ", " because they represent line breaks in addresses.  How do I do this?  I've tried the following, which doesn't seem to help:

```
  doc.inner_html.gsub!("<br/>", ", ")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply:

```ruby
doc.css('br').each{ |br| br.replace ", " }
```

Seen in action:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML('<address>900 Magnolia Road<br/>Nederland, CO<br/>80466</address>')
puts doc.root
#=> <html><body><address>900 Magnolia Road<br>Nederland, CO<br>80466</address></body></html>

doc.css('br').each{ |br| br.replace ", " }
puts doc.root
#=> <html><body><address>900 Magnolia Road, Nederland, CO, 80466</address></body></html>
```

If you want to be more careful and only replace the `<br>` inside an `<address>` tag (for example), then:

```ruby
doc.css('address > br').each{ |br| br.replace ", " }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the content like so:

```
doc.inner_html = doc.inner_html.gsub("<br/>", ", ")  # using non-bang version
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if I can't subsequently call Nokogiri's core functions (at_css, css, etc.) on inner_html, because it's a string. I need to be able to go doc.at_css etc. where doc has the modified line breaks.

Comment: you should be able to do something like `doc.at_css('header').inner_html.gsub("<br/>", ", ")`

Comment: @Dty Calling `gsub` on the inner_html won't change the DOM (nor will calling `gsub!`). You would need to use [`inner_html=`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-inner_html-3D), e.g.: `head = doc.at_css('header'); head.inner_html = head.inner_html.gsub( /<br\/?>/, ', ')`